# AWS DMS CDC task does not detect column name and type changes

Tags: postgresql, amazon-s3, parquet, cdc, aws-dms

I have created a CDC task that captures changes in a source PostgreSQL schema and writes them in Parquet format into a target S3 bucket. The task captures the inserts, updates and deletes correctly but fails to capture column name and type changes in the source.

When I change a column name or type of a table in the source and insert new rows to the table, the resulting Parquet file uses the old column name and type.

Is there a specific configuration I am missing? or it is not possible to achieve the desired outcome from this task in DMS?

Comment: if you change column at source and DMS will pick automatically from source and update at destination. check your DMS setting. you no need to do manually adding column at destination.

Comment: Any idea which configuration I am missing?

Comment: Under Table Statistics --- Validate Again you have to do it.

Comment: I posted screenshot with Answer here

Comment: This approach does not work.

Comment: according to the docs only a limited number of DDL commands are supported: TRUNCATE TABLE, DROP TABLE, and CREATE TABLE
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.S3.html

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the `HandleSourceTableAltered` parameter set to `true` in the task settings.[1]  (The setting applies when the target metadata parameter `BatchApplyEnabled` is set to either true or false.)

Same goes for `HandleSourceTableDropped` or `HandleSourceTableTruncated` if this is relevant in your case.

Obviously, previously replicated Parquet files on S3 will not change to reflect this DDL change on the source.

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.TaskSettings.DDLHandling.html

Answer (score 0):

if you change column at source and DMS will pick automatically from source and update at destination. check your DMS setting. you no need to do manually adding column at destination

[image]